# Error connecting to FTP server using ftp4j in android

Tags: java, android, file-upload, ftp, ftp4j

I get this error exactly when I use client.connect(FTP_HOST);
I have standard ftp connection and using the default port 21
anyone can help me find what is the cause of this problem?
thanks

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient [connected=false,
connector=it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.connectors.DirectConnector@4281bfb8,
security=SECURITY_FTP, authenticated=false, transfer mode=passive, 
transfer type=TYPE_AUTO, textualExtensionRecognizer=it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.extrecognizers.DefaultTextualExtensionRecognizer@4281ccd0, 
listParsers=it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.listparsers.UnixListParser@42872d30, 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.listparsers.DOSListParser@42870a40, 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.listparsers.EPLFListParser@4284c9f8, 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.listparsers.NetWareListParser@428698d0, 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.listparsers.MLSDListParser@4284e2b8, autoNoopTimeout=0]
```

//
This is my code

```
public void uploadFile(File fileName){


    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {

        client.connect(FTP_HOST);
        client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
        //client.changeDirectory("/schlogger/");

        client.upload(fileName, new MyTransferListener());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.disconnect(true);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

this is in the mainfist

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: What is FTP_HOST, FTP_USER?

Comment: FTP_HOST and FTP_USER and FTP_PASS as String values that has the host,  user name and password. I checked these info using FileZilla and I connect with no problem at all

Comment: FTP_HOST must start "ftp://"

Comment: I tried that already, same error

Comment: Are you have internet connection on device (emulator) from another app, fox example browser?

Comment: I used both the emulator and my mobile both same error and both have internet connection (I get XML data already)

Comment: and using this in the mainfist <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Are you use connect only one time, or use connect in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add after `client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);` code `client.setPassive(true); client.noop();`

Comment: the crash is in the first line client.connect(FTP_HOST); it does not reach to the setType line

Comment: Try 'client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);'

Comment: try 'client.setAutoNoopTimeout( 30000);' before 'client.connect(FTP_HOST);'

Comment: I got this error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, i think I should use in different thread